# Select a number randomly with probability proportional to its magnitude from the given array of n elements

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, random

Ex 1: A = [0 5 27 6 13 28 100 45 10 79]
let f(x) denote the number of times x getting selected in 100 experiments.
f(100) > f(79) > f(45) > f(28) > f(27) > f(13) > f(10) > f(6) > f(5) > f(0)

My code:

```
def pick_a_number_from_list(A,l):
    Sum = 0
    #l = len(A)
    for i in range(l):
        Sum+=A[i]
    A_dash = []
    for i in range(l):
        b=A[i]/Sum
        A_dash.append(b)
    #print(A_dash)
    series = pd.Series(A_dash)
    cumsum = series.cumsum(skipna=False)
    #print(cumsum[9])

    sample_value = uniform(0.0,1.0)
    r = sample_value
    print(r)
    #for i in range(l):
    if r<cumsum[1]:  
            return 1
    elif r>cumsum[1] and r <cumsum[2]:  
            return 2
    elif r<cumsum[3]: 
            return 3
    elif r<cumsum[4]: 
            return 4
    elif r<cumsum[5]: 
            return 5
    elif r<cumsum[6]:  
            return 6
    elif r<cumsum[7]: 
            return 7
    elif r<cumsum[8]: 
            return 8
    elif r<cumsum[9]:
            return 9


def sampling_based_on_magnitued():

    A = [0,5,27,6,13,28,100,45,10,79]
    n = len(A)
    #for i in range(1,10):
    num = pick_a_number_from_list(A,n)
    print(A[num])

sampling_based_on_magnitued()
```

In mu code i am using multiple if else statement and because it is hardcoded
i can make by o/p right till 10 element in the list.
I want to make my code dynamic for any value in the list.

Here in my code i have restricted it to n=10

Pls tell me how can i right generic code which can replace all if - elseif statement with for loop

Comment: Do you have to have a `for` loop? If so, why? If you don't need a `for` loop, you can just use `random.choices(A, weights=A)` if you need a single sample, or `random.choices(A, weights=A, k=100)` if you need (for example) 100 samples. But note that while `f(6) > f(5)` will be true more often than not, it's still subject to randomness (just like all the other comparisons).

Comment: there is no restriction. The only condition which i want to implement is that instead of restricting only to list of size=10. Size should be dynamic might be n=15. So my code should be smart enough to do same irrespective to the value of n. Please share your though on that

Comment: Is it always sequential values?

Answer (score 4):

```
sum1=0;
for i in A:
    sum1+=i;
x=0
list1=[]
for i in A:
    list1.append(x+i/sum1)
    x=x+i/sum1;
#list1 contsins cumulative sum
bit=uniform(0,1)
for i in range (0,len(list1)):
    if bit<list1[i]:
        return A[i]
```

you may use this

Comment: Can you please help me with step by step execution flow? I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

## you can use random.choices

```
A = [0,5, 27, 6, 13, 28, 100, 45, 10, 79]
```

## let no of random values want to pick it be 100 s0 k=100

```
w = [0.0, 0.01597444089456869, 0.08626198083067092, 0.019169329073482427, 0.04153354632587859, 0.08945686900958466, 0.3194888178913738, 0.14376996805111822, 0.03194888178913738, 0.2523961661341853]
```

## weights is calculsted by using A[i]/(total sum of all the values of A)

```
x = random.choices(A,w,k=100)

print(x)
```

## it displays the values from list A according to there weights

Answer (score 1):

Some changes in Bitan Guha Roy's code to return just one value

```
import numpy as np

sum1=0;
for i in A:
    sum1+=i;
x=0
list1=[]
for i in A:
    list1.append(x+i/sum1)
    x=x+i/sum1;
# list1 contains cumulative sum
bit=np.random.uniform(0.0,1.0,1)
for i in range (0,len(list1)):
    if bit>=list1[i] and bit<list1[i+1]:
        print(A[i+1])  # or return if under a function
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import random


lst=[0, 5 ,27, 6, 13, 28, 100, 45, 10,79]   

def pick_a_number_from_list(A):
    weights1=[]
    
    for i in A:
        weights1.append(i/sum(lst))
        
    selected_random_number = random.choices(A,weights=weights1,k=1)    
    
    return selected_random_number


def sampling_based_on_magnitued():
    for i in range(1,100):
        number=pick_a_number_from_list(lst)
        print(number)
    

sampling_based_on_magnitued()

# used random.choices which gives option to choose random number according respective weights. Please suggest any modification if you've any
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.